# The requested URL /FAQ was not found on this server.It

Tags: laravel-5

The requested URL /FAQ was not found on this server.It was on local host:8000 but its not working on remote server in laravel.

Comment: Can you explain further ? is you are getting any error on your browser ?

Comment: The requested URL / login was not found on this server.But same code is running fine on local machine after deploy code on server machine it is giving the error.

Comment: Have you installed all the required dependency of laravel on remote server which you have installed on your local ?